# Test Transaction of DOGECOIN

Tags: php, api, transactions, dogecoin-api

For making the transaction in `DOGECOIN` in my site , I have integrated the DOGECOIN API from https://www.dogeapi.com. When user click on to the checkout widget it redirects towards the page of `DOGECOIN` API and here I need to insert the PIN (UNIQUE PIN of Account), which is inserted while registering on https://www.dogeapi.com.

**PROBLEM :** The Problem is for completing  transaction we need the real doge coins but as developer we always need to do the test transaction first , so my question is how can i get the  TEST environment for `DOGECOI` TEST TRANSACTION ?

I know that DOGECOIN is introduced just before some month and there not much things are available to use it.if any of you guys have such experience to deal with it than please help me .

The INTEGRATION CODE :

```
     <?php
    //set to your API_KEY
$api_key = '************************';

//set this to your users id
//for this example we will make it 22
//must be alphanumeric only
$user_id = '22';

//set this to the amount the item costs
$amount_doge = '1000';

//send a request to the API to make a new payment address
//put info about the request in 
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.dogeapi.com/wow/?api_key=$api_key&a=get_new_address&address_label=$user_id");
if($response !== 'Bad Query' && $response !== '') {
    $new_address = json_decode($response);


    //give them the address or echo a widget here
                                    ?>
    <script src='https://www.dogeapi.com/widget/dogeapi.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <div class='doge-widget-wrapper'>
    <form method='get' action='https://www.dogeapi.com/checkout'>
        <input type='hidden' name='widget_type' value='pay'>
        <input type='hidden' name='widget_key' value='ugkzdu62opc8qlb3e41u5kthq'>
        <input type='hidden' name='new_address' value='<?php echo $new_address ?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='amount_usd' value='10'>
        <div class='doge-widget' style='display:none;'></div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
    //for this example we will just echo an address
    echo "Please pay $amount_doge DOGE to $new_address to receive your item. It may take up to 10 minutes to confirm your payment.";
    //header("Location: post-payment.php");
} else {
    echo 'There was a problem processing your order.';
}
    ?>
```

I have attached the Image of the page after checkout.

[image]